# how to make installable for java in linux

Tags: java, linux

i have developed an application in java for linux i need to install it in linux in my system(ubuntu 10.04) and how to make executable for linux .i have the application as jar file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete) and [this](http://www.offbyzero.com/resources/java_deb_ubuntu).

Comment: https://foss.in/2007/register/slides/Packaging_Java_Applications_for_Ubuntu_Platform_478.pdf

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "java -jar filename.jar" > runme.sh && chmod +x runme.sh

./runme.sh
```

Comment: I don't know much of the shell scripting, but if it works then this is what user is asking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple shell script that run the following command:

```
java -jar mylib.jar
```

and then run the script using `./myscript.sh`

Comment: hello i need to make an installable that the program should found in sound&video in menu of ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting a different machine from the one you've developed on, you'll need to package your JAR into a `.deb` file and either include a JRE/JDK in the distribution, or else declare a dependency on one of the `apt` packaged Java distros so that `apt-get` installs Java at the same time as your application.

Answer (score 0):

For Java applications with a GUI, look into [Java Web Start](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml).

I never had much luck getting menu items to work on Ubuntu Linux, but desktop shortcuts were no problem.  Maybe you can specify the exact sub-menu that the menu item is to appear under, and it will work.

JWS also works for Windows and Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this article](http://www.offbyzero.com/resources/java_deb_ubuntu) and you need to create a file with gedit and name it with your package name.(e.g totem for totem media player listed in Applications Sound & Video) then in that file enter these lines and save to Input directory (mentioned in the above tutorial)

```
?package(yourpackagename):needs="X11" \
 section="Applications/Sound" \
 title="yourpackagename" \
 command="/usr/bin/yourpackagename" \
 icon="/usr/share/pixmaps/yourpackageicon"
```

enter your package name accordingly. Icon line is optional you can omit it. then

```
debian/input/yourpackagename /usr/share/menu/yourpackagename
```

add this line to install file
there we are adding the above created file into /usr/share/menu dir